# Spring + Jsf Актуально ли?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsf, spring-webflow

Добрый день.Вот начинаем старые проекты переносить на новые технологии и выбераем технолонический стэк.Это интенрнет магазины тд тп .сам `Spring mvc` использует `jsp` что как бы совсем не удобно когда проекты растет ,нам всёже по душе Jsf особоенно его либы типо `(`Primafeces`,`Bootfaces`и тд)`.Но как вообще такая связка со  `Spring mvc` + `JSF` как бы это 2 разных фреймворка один основан на компонентах другой на запросах ,такая связка в будущем создаст больше проблем ?или её можно смело тягать ?хотелось бы услышать доводы так же

Comment: Spring MVC может использовать и другой шаблонизатор. Например, Thymeleaf. А пытаться спарить Spring MVC с JSF - это плохая идея, у них в корне разные подходы.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev насаом деле jsf хоть и какашка но мы её юзаем скалой )шикарно прёт , но согласен так как спринг и jsf  совсем разные подходы .Спасибо за ваше мнение